# Angular Material 2, how to theme Select Dropdown

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

Trying to change the default style of this component :

https://material.angular.io/components/component/select

It has several classes like

```
.mat-select-placeholder, .mat-select-value
```

But I can't figure out from their documentation how to change the color of these without overriding the styles in my own css.

I tried adding `color="accent"` but had no effect. Would like the change the color to white.

Is this currently possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it to be good practice to load a separate custom stylesheet after the angular material and override the styles.

1. Separation of concerns as `Material` css stays separate from your personal css allowing you to organize files and `<style>` order
2. If `Material` upgrades to a newer version, your hack or change will have to be reapplied.